# Core Data multiple relationships to same entity

Tags: iphone, core-data, relationships

I have a data model I'm trying to port from a SQLite based table structure to a Core Data model.    My SQLite structure has a Zones table and a TransitLogs table.    A TransitLog can have the following (in my sqlite schema)
start_zone_id
end_zone_id

Each of which is a foreign key to the zones table.    This works fine in SQL.    But when moving to Core Data I'm having trouble understanding how to model this.

My first attempt has me having two relationships in my TransitLog Entity with a startZone and endZone relationship attributes that point to a Zone (sorry wasn't able to post a screenshot of xcode as this is my first post here)

The question I have is how to handle the inverse relationship for the startZone and endZone relationship attributes.    Do I not need them?   In the documentation and books I've read on this topic, it's best to always use an inverse relationship but I'm wondering about this particular situation if it doesn't apply.   Or am I simply modeling this incorrectly in Core Data.

Thanks for any advice.

Mike

Answer (score 3):

You can have two separate to-many relationships in the Zone entity that point to TransitLog, called something like `startLogs` and `endLogs`.  Those would be the inverses for `startZone` and `endZone`, respectively.

Comment: Note that the inverse relationships although not absolutely required in a compilation/syntax sense are necessary to allow CoreData to update the many set when the one is deleted.

Comment: If you are never going to need to go from Zones to TransitLogs, then you can do without the inverse relationship. It does not seem that deleting a TransitLog would have any effect on its startZone and endZone. So, it seems that you would be fine to omit inverse relationships. However, if you think that you will ever ever want to, say count how many transit logs originate from each zone, then you might want to add inverse relationships now and save yourself the migration effort later on.

Answer (score 2):

Nontrivial model versioning and migration can be a real time sink - especially the first time. For that reason, as well as that Apple recommends using them, I would recommend adding the inverse relationships.

That said, I have found at least one case where it simply did not make sense to add an inverse relationship - and everything works fine. But in that case there it was (and remains) extremely difficult to find a scenario where the inverse relationship would *ever* be useful or necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys - both answers helped a lot.  Westsider is right I currently have no need to traverse from the zone down to the TransitLogs and was why I was wondering.   But that being said I guess it is possible that I might need them at some point (thousands of users clamoring for it hopefully ;)) so probably better to model it now.

Thanks again for the answers.